Rename a file based on value present in the name value in the content
I have a XML file as below and the file name is "data.xml"
<ns0:LovData xmlns:ns0="http://teamcenter.com/Schemas/Soa/2011-06/MetaModel">
<ns0:lovs name="infolist" attachedProps="" uid="iDM99Y1PaIuwkD" attachedSpecs="" usage="Exhaustive" typeName="ListOfValuesString" description="BOM Grading LOV." attachedTypes=""/>
</ns0:LovData>

How can I rename this file into "infolist.xml" which is the name coming from the lovs name="infolist"?
I'm not able to read the XML file in batch.

Are you looking for an answer based on a batch script or PowerShell? You've tagged your question with both, but you say "I'm not able to read the XML file in batch.". I'm not clear if you mean you're looking for an answer in pure batch, or if you're ruling it out as possible. In powershell it's pretty simple: $data = [xml] (Get-Content $oldFile -Raw); $newName = $data.LovData.lovs.name; Move-Item $oldFile "$newName.xml"...

@mclayton, thanks for the answer. Can we apply this script for multiple files?

"Can we apply this script for multiple files? " - short answer, "yes" :-). Long answer - depends on how and what you want to do. To get started, have a read of  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.4

Answer based on mclayton command mclayton comment
$path = "path\to\folder"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Filter *xml

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $data = [xml] (Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw)
    $NewName = $data.LovData.lovs.name
    Rename-Item -Path $file -NewName $NewName
}


I tried this, it's worked. thanks a lot
